# Why do I still have to manually create and link my account for every stack exchange web site?

Tags: feature-request

I've been waiting patiently for this to be fixed, but now I'm beginning to think that the devs don't realize this obvious problem.

*Of course* I want my account created/linked when I visit a new stack exchange website. You have no idea how many upvotes and insightful comments you've missed out on because people's accounts were not automatically created and linked, and it was too much effort to go through that process just to click an upvote button.

Comment: It already asks you when you attempt to log in on the new site... Seriously... It takes me like 5 seconds to click log in, click Google, click the Always allow this site button, and click Link my accounts. Then it even redirects you back to the page you were on before you click log in. How is that too much effort?

Comment: In addition, I do not think that upvotes or answers go lost because of this. If someone wants to become a member, he or she us making a decision to become part of the community. I think the number of people that is browsing random SE sites and is not voting because of this is very small...

Comment: Way to kill the messenger. I don't care if you downvote me into oblivion, I will continue to fight for the user. You guys are all in denial of this obvious problem.

Comment: @superjoe reputation works differently on Meta than it works on the main sites: Here, it is a mere expression of disagreement, especially on feature requests. There is nothing wrong with your suggestion, people just don't think it should be implemented. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @superjoe so you think animuson's comment has no validity at all?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I suspect that those sites don't *want* users who can't be bothered to put in the trivial amount of effort required to jump through the hoops. You could see it as an implicit filter.

Comment: Curiously I was referred to your -14 question when I asked about how login works(!). Seems like your question wasn't that bad after all. There needs to be more help pages on this site.  I would not suspect I should be doing searches to find out common information.  Help should be help not about.

Answer (score 22):

You mean one should automatically have an account on every Stack Exchange site that gets created?

Among other things, that would lead to

- People having accounts on sites they might not *want* to have an account on (Guns, various Religion sites, Sex, Science Fiction, Role Playing, Atheism.... So many fields that some people wouldn't want to touch with a *stick*! And you want to give them accounts on every one of them?)
- Every new SE site starting out with a totally misleading number of users, and thousands of zombie accounts
- The list of "my accounts" growing *massive* for every user

I think it's perfectly okay to make joining a site a conscious decision.

Comment: Was that Sex or Tex?

Comment: Mostly about Latex in both anyway @GUI

Comment: At the very least, when I click "upvote" or "comment" it should just work. If it means creating and linking an account, so be it.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I certainly don't. The current behavior is just fine.

There are some Stack Exchange sites I do *not* want to be associated with if I follow a random link or sidebar site promotion.

Linking your account is a matter of a few clicks, that you only need to do once per site. If you really want to upvote/comment/interact with a Stack Exchange site, that's a very small price to pay (and the association bonus is just icing on the cake).